# What is the best tool to query delimited text files in Java?

Tags: java, csv, text, hsqldb

I need to execute basic queries on a text file which consists of several columns. I tried to use StelsCSV which is a JDBC Driver for CSV files. It is good but commercial. Do you know other tools for the same task?

Comment: There's a similar question on Super User: http://superuser.com/questions/7169/querying-a-csv-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HSQL](http://www.hsqldb.org/) has functionality for manipulatng csv data, and it's open source.

Comment: More information is available here: http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch06.html

Answer (score 2):

Haven't used this but here is one: http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/

Also: https://xlsql.dev.java.net/

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to parse the text files and store them in an embedded database like HypersonicDB. Once there, they can be queried using SQL.

How practical this is would depend how often the files change, and how expensive it is to parse and load them. Only you can answer that, but it may be worth considering. For example, if you run frequent queries against the data, it may be worth the up-front cost of loading into the DB, since each query should be more efficient.

Of course, you also get the advantage of using a "proper" supported database.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do this as a database driver, or just an easy way to parse a CSV file?

My personal opinion is that JDBC/etc... for this sort of thing is *way* overkill.  If you are good with using a simple reader interface, and having things be lightweight, and 'just work', check out [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: JDBC is not a must but since I need to execute some simple queries, I thought such a thing would be a better choice although it is a bit heavy weight.

Comment: I'd parse the CSV directly and just work with the iterator.  It will be much, much faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can use MySQL to do the job.

Take a look at:

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/csv-storage-engine.html

Answer (score 0):

[Super CVS](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/) is a nice library and it is free software.